# Angular not defined

Tags: javascript

C:\angualr\csap\Finished\app.js:1
(function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);
                                                                          ^

ReferenceError: angular is not defined

at Object. (C:\angualr\csap\Finished\app.js:1:75)    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:701:30)    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:712:10)    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:600:32)    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:539:12)    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:531:3)    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:754:12)    at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:283:19)    at bootstrapNodeJSCore (internal/bootstrap/node.js:622:3)

Comment: If the project is setup to use modules – as the appearance of `exports`, `require`, etc. suggests – Angular likely won't be available as a global variable. You probably have to [import it](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import), similar at least to `import angular from 'angular'`, before using `angular.module()`.

Answer (score 0):

You have not included the Angular main library, without knowing how you are building your project it is impossible to resolve your issue. You could always just add the library from a CDN to the top of your page.

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.7.5/angular.min.js"></script>
```